# Okta Redirect Url Not working when HashLocationStrategy is enabled in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing, okta, hash-location-strategy

I am trying to add Okta SSO in my application. But because of `HashLocationStrategy` okta not able to parse token.

Is there any way to turn off `HashLocationStrategy` for specific route?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a hash delimiter # to your redirect url, i solved the problem for me

moved from

```
redirect_uri: `${configdata.clientRoot}/${lang}/#/auth-callback`,
```

to

```
redirect_uri: `${configdata.clientRoot}/${lang}/#/auth-callback#`,
```

Comment: Thank you for response. But after adding # it saying bad request. I have added like this:
"redirectUri": "http://localhost:4200/#/implicit/callback#"

Comment: have you made this update on both server and client sides?

Comment: I tried to update url with # in okta, but its giving error as `The redirect URIs must be absolute URIs.`